# Why does Ceebox trigger duplicate iframes and links?

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal

I am working on a drupal site that has a form submit ajax call to a function that triggers ceebox. Code for drupal php function is as follows:

```
    $commands = array();
    $html = '<a title="" style="display:none;" href="/subscribe" class="ceebox" id="subscribe" rel="iframe width:500 height:350"></a>';
//attempt to remove already existing ceebox generated elements
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#subscribe','');
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#cee_iframeContent', '');
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#cee_title', '');
    $commands[] = ajax_command_append('body', $html);
    $commands[] = ajax_command_invoke(NULL, 'subscribeOpen', array('subscribe'));
    return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands'=>$commands);
```

Javascript that drupal function calls:

```
(function($) {
        $.fn.subscribeOpen = function(data) {

            $('#subscribe').ceebox().trigger('click');


        };



})(jQuery);
```

This all works as expected; ie brings up the ceebox containing /subscribe page content in an iframe. When I click close link on the ceebox or click the background to close, it shuts down first time. When I then click on the subscribe link to trigger the drupal ajax and ceebox call it adds an extra close link, an extra 'Item 1 of 1' title and an extra iFrame window. This repeats everytime I click close and then trigger the function add infinitum. I have tried to add unbind('#ceebox') to the #subscribe element as well as various combinations of jQuery unique() methodto no avail. Could anyone shed light on how to unbind/remove these duplicate ceeboxes please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out by taking a look through the jquery.ceebox.js file and found the intialise function to have a live() method running on it.

This will cause all kinds of wonderful issues as it should only ever be called once on an element. The above code would call live() multiple times when triggering ceebox, therefore I would recommend that you replace line 374 of jquery.ceebox.js:

```
$(elem).live("click", function(e){
```

to read:

```
$(elem).bind("click", function(e){
```